# How to read text file line by line which is excessing characters in batch file? Limiting the line length is allowed.(Windows, batch script)

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, cmd

```
##test.txt##
First line = 1;*|:12345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345
Second line = 5;*|:3215432;*|:21543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215;*|:543215;*|:5432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321543215432154321
```

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "test.txt"') do (
            set "Line=%%a"
            echo Line: "!Line!"
)
```

Obviously, the above code cannot read 2 lines in test.txt, since each line is over the limit(8191 characters).

By typing

```
type "test.txt"
```

It still resulted in the 2 lines as in the test.txt file. However, as soon as 2 lines get in the for loop, the lines cannot be read.

I do not need the whole length of line, so I tried to preprocess the text file, by deleting excessing part of the string. For example, limit the line length as 8100 in the above example.

1.How do I edit the above text file without using notepad(any GUI editors) in windows environment?

2.If I do not need to preprocess the file, what is the trick to avoid the above issue?

- Even I cannot put carrot(^), which extends the line of command. What I want is it is fine to split the string and take first parts, but I do not want to do it manually via notepad or other GUI file editors.

Comment: Depends on the file content. Does it contain only numbers/letters or also colons/whitespaces?

Comment: @jeb it also contains colons and other special characters, such as (,),% etc.

Comment: Are the first columns size limited? How many do you need? Can you use `|` as a delimiter?

Comment: @jeb Thanks for following. No, I cannot use | as a delimiter, since the line would be seperated by first '=' equal sign. If you mean, First line and Second line parts as the first columns.. it is not fixed and limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a chunk reader, it splits each line into chunks of a maximum size of 1023 characters, each.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set pos=0
set line=
<long_text.txt (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%1 in ('findstr /o "^" long_text.txt') DO (
        set new_pos=%%1
        set /a size=new_pos-pos
        set /a "chunks=(size-1+1022) / 1023"
        if defined line echo Line: !line! chunks=!chunks!

        set /a pos=new_pos
        for /L %%# in (1 1 !chunks!) do (
            set "partial="
            set /p partial=     
            if defined partial (
                echo   #!line! chunk %%# -- !partial:~0,10! ... !partial:~-10! 
            )
        )
        set /a line+=1
    )
)
```

#### How it works

The outer `FOR /F .. findstr /O` loop is used to determine the length of each line, by calculating the positional difference between two lines.
The line length is used to calculate how many *chunks* has to be read to fetch the whole line.

A line itself is read by `set /p` (it reads from the redirection of `<long_text.txt`).
  `set /p` has a build in limit of 1023 characters.

Therefore `set /p` is used *chunk* times.

To calculate how many chunks are used for a single line, the line length has to be divided by 1023, but 1 character has to be subtracted, because the LF doesn't count (but the CR). The `+1022` is a result of the fact, that the remaining characters after the last *complete* chunk has to be read, too.
The last chunk can be empty, if the line is a multiple of 1023 (also an empty line).

The only remaining point is the last line.
The last line will not be read by this technique, but it's easy enough to append one empty line before.

Comment: The code works, I would work on based on this chunk reader. Thanks a lot! @jeb

Comment: I am not sure that why the code is set new_pos=%%1 now. With %%2, it works, but not with %%1. There was a wrong update I think.

Comment: @JoeyCho, I suppose you didn't copy the complete updated code. First I used `%%2` with two tokens and `findstr /N /O`, but I removed the superfluous parts

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. Change the `20` to the maximum number of characters you need from each line.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\longlines.txt' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { $_.substring(0,[Math]::min($_.Length, 20)) }"
```